# Are the two approaches behave the same?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Both of the following codes process the items in the list in parallel, with a threshold of degree of parallelism of 5. Are they effectively the same?

**Parallel.ForEach with MaxDegreeOfParallelism**

```
public async Task Run()
{
    var list = // List<....>
    Parallel.ForEach(list, 
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5}, d => {
            ....
            process(d).RunSynchronously();
            ....
    });
}
```

**Extension method using `Partitioner.Create(...).GetPartitions(...)`**

```
public async Task Run()
{
    var list = // List<....>
    await list.ForEachAsync(list.Count() / 5 + 1, async d =>
    {
        ....
        await process(d);
        ....
    });
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body)
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(
            from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
            select Task.Run(async delegate {
                using (partition)
                    while (partition.MoveNext())
                        await body(partition.Current);
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: The first sends an async delgate to `Parallel.Foreach` which results in an unawaited async void. `Parallel.Foreach` is not intended for async operations but instead only for CPU bound code.

Comment: I've updated the question and call the async method synchronously for the first one.

Comment: Five downvoters, why?

Answer (score 1):

`Parallel.Foreach` uses default partitioner. If you have a small job to perform then this could be overhead as each partition will be calculated and each will be a delegate that will be invoked with each iteration.

This overhead can be fixed using partitions. It enables you to provide a sequential loop for the delegate body, so that the delegate is invoked only once per partition, instead of once per iteration. Also you can control the Partitioning by using your partitioner.

```
 Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0L, SUMTOP), (range) =>
            {
                long local = 0;
                for (long i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++) local += i;
                Interlocked.Add(ref sum, local);
            });
```

The second implementation does similar job but Asynchronously and you have more command on partitioning. It will handle the overhead of small jobs.
Hope this explanation will help you make a choice.

Comment: Will `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` in the first implementation control the partitioning? Not sure about the first paragraph of your answer, the list may have one several to hundreds of items.

Comment: `Small job` refers to workload that will happen in each iteration. It doesn't matter how many iteration do you have. If workload is small sequential for may run faster then parallel.